# Returning a list of even fibonacci numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I am working my way through Problem 2 on the Project Euler page

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the
>   previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will
>   be: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... By considering the terms in
>   the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find
>   the sum of the even-valued terms.

Before I sum all of the even numbers, I want to generate a list of them.

I have created the following methods:

```
    static List<int> Fibonacci(int n)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        var list = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int temp = a;
            a = b;
            b = temp + b;
            list.Add(a);
        }
        return list;
    }

    static List<int> ListEvenFibonacci(int n)
    {
        var list = Fibonacci(n);
        var evenList = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            if (IsEvan(list.ElementAt(i)))
            {
                evenList.Add(i);
            }
        }

        return evenList;
    }

    static bool IsEvan(int n)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

And in my main function I am printing out the even list of numbers to make sure it works like so:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var List = ListEvenFibonacci(15);
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(List[i]);
        }
    }
```

however, the output I am getting is not correct:

```
2
5
8
11
14
```

Comment: so what's the question here?

Comment: Why make a separate `IsEven` function instead of just writing `if (i % 2 == 0)...`? Also, `==` is *already* a Boolean expression, so you don't need to explicitly return true and false, just `return (i % 2 == 0);`

Comment: You are saving the index of the even number in your list. Change it to evenlist.Add(list[I]);

Comment: Generate your list, then use LINQ: `fibonacciList.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Sum();`

Comment: @maccettura U mean ToList()?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the OP wants the **sum of all even Fibonacci numbers**

Comment: You're adding the index not the number.  Also just use `list[i]` instead of `ElementAt`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest implementing a *generator* and then, with a help of *Linq* perform the query:

```
private static IEnumerable<long> Fibo(long first, long second) {
  long prior = first;
  long last = second;

  yield return prior; 
  yield return last; 

  while (true) {
    long next = prior + last;

    yield return next;

    prior = last;
    last = next; 
  } 
}
```

...

```
long result = Fibo(1, 2)
  //.Where((value, index) => index % 2 == 0) // if we want even indexes (zero based!)
  .Where(value => value % 2 == 0)            // if we want even values
  .TakeWhile(value => value <= 4000000)      // items not exceed 4e6
  .Sum(); 

Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome: **4613732**

Answer (score 1):

You're adding an iteration variable, not the list element itself.

```
evenList.Add(i);
```

Should be

```
 evenList.Add(list[i]);
```

Comment: Or even shorthand it as ```list[i]```.

Comment: @B.K.
Yeah, totally makes sense. I've fallen into a trap of repeating a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't save index of even number. Save the number at index like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (IsEvan(list.ElementAt(i)))
        evenList.Add(list.ElementAt(i));
}
```

> For sum of even values

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
    sum += List[i];
Console.WriteLine(sum); // this will print sum of even number.
```